# Fertilizers with harmful levels of salts

Tags: soil, fertilizer

I read in some articles that potassium chloride and ammonium sulphate can lead to salinity buildup. Is there a simple way to tell by looking at the fertilizer formula if a fertilizer can increase salt levels in the soil?

Comment: If you link the articles, we may check them (to see if they are reputable, or the many copy paste which misses often the main topic). "Salt" is also used in chemistry for different things, but you wrote "salinity" which usually we link to NaCl (so the table salt/sea salt). I would be very surprised: overfertilizing is common, but most plant do no like salinity.

Comment: Fertilizers are mostly salts so the question does not make technical sense.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi The technical definition of "salinity" includes every dissolved salt, not just sodium chloride. That commonly includes potassium ions, though it's not so obvious why the OP mentioned ammonium sulphate.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Well, too much of a good thing can kill you (and also kill plants) but I agree it's not very clear what the OP is trying to find out.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi here is a video where they talk about Chlorine as well as salt index. When I pick a fertilizer how can I compare products and pick the least damaging one for salt sensitive plants. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ld0xMwuptcE

Comment: My favorite which I use on all ornamentals  is 9 /45 / 15 .. I lists no Na but in the fine print = 12% Cl ; So I can't recommend it as "salt" free . But it grows stuff if that is the objective.